# How to represent a Focus as a function of State in React/Preact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, accessibility, preact

I am building a Date Picker component using Preact. So far, I have managed to get animations right and completed event handling. The component has interactions as shown in the following image:

[image]

The component itself is split into many smaller components where each component has some notion of its local state:

- Calendar - Top level component managing state and animation/transitions between views
- CenturyView - Renders list of years
- YearView - Renders list of months of a given year
- MonthView - Day picker that basically renders days of a given month.

This Calendar can be used as a standalone inline-widget in a page or can be used in picker/dropdown like style as shown below. Next task is to build keyboard accessibility for the component. And, that has been leading nowhere. Focus management quickly becomes mess.

Since React Component or component system is about segregating State from UI or more about making `UI = Function(State)`, what is the best way to manage **Focus** related state? By its very nature, focus in imperative operation and often handled using `useRef` and `useImperativeHandle` but these primitives are not enough to make keyboard accessibility easily possible in such complex scenarios.

So the questions are:

- What is the best way to handle Focus state?
- How to transition focus between different DOM elements of sibling components (MonthView to YearView or vice-a-versa)?
- What is the best way to change focus between different DOM elements using keyboard arrow keys?